# "ERROR TypeError: can't dup NilClass" in a Rails 3 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, typeerror

"ERROR TypeError: can't dup NilClass" in a Rails 3 app?  Any ideas - I'm just hitting the home page and get this...it was working just before...

```
Gregs-MacBook-Pro:source_rails greg$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [universal-darwin11.0]
Gregs-MacBook-Pro:source_rails greg$ rails -v
Rails 3.2.1
Gregs-MacBook-Pro:source_rails greg$ rails new test3
      create
      create  README.rdoc
      create  Rakefile
      create  config.ru
      create  .gitignore
      create  Gemfile
      create  app
      create  app/assets/images/rails.png
      create  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
      create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
      create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
      create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
      create  app/mailers
      create  app/models
      create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
      create  app/mailers/.gitkeep
      create  app/models/.gitkeep
      create  config
      create  config/routes.rb
      create  config/application.rb
      create  config/environment.rb
      create  config/environments
      create  config/environments/development.rb
      create  config/environments/production.rb
      create  config/environments/test.rb
      create  config/initializers
      create  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
      create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
      create  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
      create  config/initializers/secret_token.rb
      create  config/initializers/session_store.rb
      create  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
      create  config/locales
      create  config/locales/en.yml
      create  config/boot.rb
      create  config/database.yml
      create  db
      create  db/seeds.rb
      create  doc
      create  doc/README_FOR_APP
      create  lib
      create  lib/tasks
      create  lib/tasks/.gitkeep
      create  lib/assets
      create  lib/assets/.gitkeep
      create  log
      create  log/.gitkeep
      create  public
      create  public/404.html
      create  public/422.html
      create  public/500.html
      create  public/favicon.ico
      create  public/index.html
      create  public/robots.txt
      create  script
      create  script/rails
      create  test/fixtures
      create  test/fixtures/.gitkeep
      create  test/functional
      create  test/functional/.gitkeep
      create  test/integration
      create  test/integration/.gitkeep
      create  test/unit
      create  test/unit/.gitkeep
      create  test/performance/browsing_test.rb
      create  test/test_helper.rb
      create  tmp/cache
      create  tmp/cache/assets
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts/.gitkeep
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.gitkeep
      create  vendor/plugins
      create  vendor/plugins/.gitkeep
         run  bundle install
Enter your password to install the bundled RubyGems to your system:
Fetching source index for https://rubygems.org/
Using rake (0.9.2.2)
Using i18n (0.6.0)
Using multi_json (1.0.4)
Using activesupport (3.2.1)
Using builder (3.0.0)
Using activemodel (3.2.1)
Using erubis (2.7.0)
Using journey (1.0.1)
Using rack (1.4.1)
Using rack-cache (1.1)
Using rack-test (0.6.1)
Using hike (1.2.1)
Using tilt (1.3.3)
Using sprockets (2.1.2)
Using actionpack (3.2.1)
Using mime-types (1.17.2)
Using polyglot (0.3.3)
Using treetop (1.4.10)
Using mail (2.4.1)
Using actionmailer (3.2.1)
Using arel (3.0.0)
Using tzinfo (0.3.31)
Using activerecord (3.2.1)
Using activeresource (3.2.1)
Using bundler (1.0.22)
Using coffee-script-source (1.2.0)
Using execjs (1.3.0)
Using coffee-script (2.2.0)
Using rack-ssl (1.3.2)
Using json (1.6.5)
Using rdoc (3.12)
Using thor (0.14.6)
Using railties (3.2.1)
Using coffee-rails (3.2.2)
Using jquery-rails (2.0.0)
Using rails (3.2.1)
Using sass (3.1.15)
Using sass-rails (3.2.4)
Using sqlite3 (1.3.5)
Using uglifier (1.2.3)
Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
Gregs-MacBook-Pro:source_rails greg$
Gregs-MacBook-Pro:source_rails greg$ cd test3
Gregs-MacBook-Pro:test3 greg$
Gregs-MacBook-Pro:test3 greg$ rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.1)
>> exit
Gregs-MacBook-Pro:test3 greg$ rails server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.1 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2012-02-13 09:19:59] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2012-02-13 09:19:59] INFO  ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10) [universal-darwin11.0]
[2012-02-13 09:19:59] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=8435 port=3000
[2012-02-13 09:20:27] ERROR TypeError: can't dup NilClass
        /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httprequest.rb:204:in `dup'
        /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httprequest.rb:204:in `meta_vars'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:34:in `service'
        /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:104:in `service'
        /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:65:in `run'
        /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:173:in `start_thread'
        /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start'
        /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start_thread'
        /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:95:in `start'
        /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `each'
        /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `start'
        /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:23:in `start'
        /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:82:in `start'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:13:in `run'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:265:in `start'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:55
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:50
        script/rails:6:in `require'
        script/rails:6
```

UPDATE:

oh dear,

Just when to latest ruby 1.9.3 using rvm, but I'm still getting same error - basically can't use rails at all at the moment:

```
Gregs-MacBook-Pro:test_rvm193_1 greg$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-darwin11.3.0]
Gregs-MacBook-Pro:test_rvm193_1 greg$ which ruby
/Users/greg/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/ruby
Gregs-MacBook-Pro:test_rvm193_1 greg$ rails -v
Rails 3.2.1
Gregs-MacBook-Pro:test_rvm193_1 greg$

Gregs-MacBook-Pro:test_rvm193_1 greg$ rails server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.1 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2012-02-13 11:30:11] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2012-02-13 11:30:11] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2011-10-30) [x86_64-darwin11.3.0]
[2012-02-13 11:30:11] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=36488 port=3000
[2012-02-13 11:30:32] ERROR TypeError: can't dup NilClass
        /Users/greg/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httprequest.rb:273:in `dup'
        /Users/greg/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httprequest.rb:273:in `meta_vars'
        /Users/greg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:34:in `service'
        /Users/greg/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
        /Users/greg/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
        /Users/greg/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
^C[2012-02-13 11:31:04] INFO  going to shutdown ...
```

Any ideas?

Comment: arrr - I noted I had "https" not "http" in the url I was calling.  That is I was using "https://localhost:3000".   Should this have had such an effect on rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

arrr - I noted I had "https" not "http" in the url I was calling. That is I was using "localhost:3000";. Should this have had such an effect on rails?